# Can we reopen the question “When would the Undying Lands become over-populated?”

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

The question [When would the Undying Lands become over-populated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227754/when-would-the-undying-lands-become-over-populated) was closed as opinion-based, but it has a definitive answer (never) because of specific things that Tolkien wrote. OP's assumption of "natural increase" in the Undying Lands is unfounded.

Comment: You have my reopen vote. That being said, if your answer doesn't meet the hype, I'm gonna press the down button and never trust you again :-)

Comment: Saw your meta after the reopen queue, voted to reopen now. To be honest when voting to close I thought it was either going to be opinion based or the answer would be “no/never”.

Answer (score 4):

I was the fifth reopen vote just now. Go ahead and post your answer.